# Will HTML5 support the access of offline cached audio?

Tags: caching, audio, html

We want to make an audio based web based app that will have many sound snippets.  We want to cache these files so that performance is good and not dependent on network speed.  Can HTML5  cache audio for offline mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It certainly seems to me that this *should* work, and I can't find any documentation that says it shouldn't work (either from the W3C or from vendors like Apple), but putting audio files as resources in cache manifest just doesn't seem to work with Safari on the iPad & iPhone at least.

Sounds play fine when the app is in online (although it seems to load them anew each time and not cache them) and it doesn't complain about the resources not being there when in offline mode (which is does immediately if you forget to include a JavaScript, CSS, HTML or image resource).

Instead of complaining (or loading); if the element has a control that control is replaced with a box that says "Cannot play audio file.". Alternatively, if it's an element without a control - i.e. accessed via JavaScript all to .play() - then it simply just doesn't play (it doesn't cause any errors, there is just no sound, the JavaScript otherwise continues to execute normally).

I have tested this with pretty small (<20k) files and the result is the same, so it doesn't seem to be size related, just a blanket refusal to copy. <strike>I'm not sure if you can encode sound as a resource in a page (e.g. encoded in base64) the way you can with images, but I'm going to investigate that option - I suspect that would be possible.</strike> I tried encoding audio data as data URI strings and even tried generating audio on the fly - both work fine in Safari on the desktop but do not work on the iPhone / iPad OS (at least on version 3.x - I have not tried on iOS 4, but it won't be out for a week, and is not expected for the iPad for a few months, even if they do fix it).

I would guess the refusal to cache sound files in iOS is an implementation bug or intended limited functionality. It's certainly annoying and a show stopper for a lot of use cases.

I am not sure what happens with other HTML5 clients, I'd be interested to know (in particular on Andriod). Google's support for audio hasn't been stellar either, so it may suffer from the same limitations.

Comment: FYI the reason JavaScript .play() does not work on the control less element is because it is disallowed in safari for iphone/ipad (there has to be user input). As for the "Cannot play audio file", I have found it to be happening because the file was not supported. This has happened to me with certain mp3 files, for some reason.

Comment: @jd Thanks, but to clarify, what I see is that the JavaScript actually DOES work fine but ONLY if you have (fast) connectivity (if it's slow it's intermittent, because it keeps re-fetching the sound files). The cache manifest is just not honoured for sound files in offline HTML5 apps - with connectivity the JavaScript calls do work (and all of the sound files work). This appears to be regardless of file size.

Comment: Thanks for this write up. I had just tested it myself and it is consistent with what you've said. Big bummer.

Comment: @Crashalot No, but I was just wondering about this with the release of iOS 5 (Apple closed my bug report 8116889 as I never got round to providing an example). I'll try it and see later.

Comment: Did you see these posts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655917/issues-playing-soundclips-with-html5-audio-on-iphone/7665336#comment9507710_7665336 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514596/mobile-web-app-and-offline-access-to-audio-files/7519720#comment9507586_7519720

Answer (score 1):

You could always develop a decoding/encoding layer that talks to the client SQLlite DB

Comment: Isn't there a 5 meg limit for storage per app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you can't specify audio files in the [cache manifest](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#manifests).

Comment: Seems there might be issues, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612116/html5-local-storage-of-audio-element-source-is-it-possible