# Mobile web app and offline access to audio files

Tags: html, caching, audio, mobile

Is it possible to cache audio files for an offline access in a mobile web app using an HTML5 cache manifest ?
I also don't understand how size limitations works. (I read 5MB limit for iOS)
I don't find resources for that or best practices.

Thanks for your help

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970062/will-html5-support-the-access-of-offline-cached-audio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612116/html5-local-storage-of-audio-element-source-is-it-possible

Comment: Thanks David for pointing these out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep - all files that are listed in the AppCache are cached by the browser, no matter if they're HTML files, JavaScript, or audio files.  As long as they're explictly mentioned in the CACHE section, they'll be available offline.

For a good AppCache tutorial, check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/, which walks you through everything you should need.

The size limit prevents you from storing too much content on a users computer.  In most cases, this isn't a problem if you're just storing HTML, CSS, JavaScript and some images, but in your case, if you're storing music, you potentially will hit that limit quickly.  Most browsers limit you to storing a maximum of 5 megs (for all content), so you'll need to be mindful of that.

Chrome has a great set of tools for debugging appcache, as you're developing your site, open the Developer Tools and watch the console to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks dude.
I thought that this 5M limit is not a real limit because the user is warned and asked if he wants to increase the limit by 5M. Is that right ?

Comment: No problem - some browsers will prompt, but others won't.  For example, mobile browsers typically won't prompt, where as desktop will.

Comment: This answer conflicts with previous SO posts like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970062/will-html5-support-the-access-of-offline-cached-audio. Are those posts outdated, or are you doing something different? I hope you're right!

Comment: Caching of audio files still does not work on Android phones regardless of the size of audio files.

Answer (score 0):

Caching of audio files via a cache manifest file still does not work on Android phones up to version 5.1.  I cannot speak for Android 6 or iPhones, iPads, since I don't have such devices.  But I tried it on Android 5.1 and Android 3 with mp3 files with a size of only 2 Kb and they were not cached on these phones whereas 200 Kb js files were cached.

The current solution seems to be to encode the mp3 files with base 64 and to put it into js files which can be cached.  A nice description of that can be found on http://grinninggecko.com/2011/04/09/html5-offline-audio/.