# issues playing soundclips with HTML5 Audio on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, html, audio

I have a few mp3 soundclips to play at certain events on my HTML5 app. There's no  tag, the script creates Audio objects at the beginning (one for each mp3) and loads the files. When I have to play a sound, I simply call play() on one of these objects.

This works fine in a Chrome desktop, but is very inconsistent in my iPod touch, eventually some sounds stop playing and I even get error alerts.

Here's a small script I set up to see the problem, it's hosted at [soundtest.staticloud.com](http://soundtest.staticloud.com) including the 3 audio files so you can check it out on an iPhone/whatever.

```
var snd = [];

window.onload = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        snd[i] = new Audio("snd" + i + ".mp3");
        snd[i].load();
    }
}

function sound(n) {
    snd[n-1].play();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a ton of audio problems in iDevices...what you have to do is blank out the last played clip before starting the next. Also, I just had a single audio object, and would change the source, so my solution looked more like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<audio></audio>
etc
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sounds=[];

window.onload = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        sounds[i] = "snd" + i + ".mp3";
    }
}

function sound(n){
snd=document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
snd.pause();  //-----------------PAUSE THE LAST (WHICH MAY BE LONG DONE)
snd.src='';   //-----------------BLANK SRC
snd.src=sounds[n-1];  //---------REPLACE WITH NEW SOUND
snd.load();
snd.play();
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I uploaded it to try it out... snd0.mp3 is failing, but I'll assume iOS has a problem with that file. The other two seem to work OK except that they take long since the button tap, and it doesn't get any faster on subsequent taps, as if the audio file is downloaded everytime it is played. Is this normal and is there any way around it?? Thanks

Comment: You can use cache.manifest to store the files on the users device (also enables functionality offline)

Comment: Interesting. Couldn't make it work yet though, I'll keep looking into this. Thanks...

Comment: Any update? Other SO posts indicate there could be issues with caching audio files, but hopefully those posts are outdated ...