# Storing audio files in html5 local storage- downloading audio files with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, jplayer

I searched and found that html5 does not support directly storing audio. I will convert audios to base64 strings and then I will store in the local storage.

I am developing a html5 audio player application with jplayer. I have audios in the server and I need to store them in the local storage, so I need to download audio files with javascript.
Is there way to download audio files with javascript?
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Safari does local audio storage http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I could not find how safari supports storing audio in local storage. Can you give exact section that explains it?

Comment: how's it going? Cracked it using Offline Application Cache? I'll be needing this functionality soon, too..

Comment: Related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612116/html5-local-storage-of-audio-element-source-is-it-possible

Answer (score 5):

Local storage tends to be limited in size (5mb ish?  can't find a reference) so this is unlikely to work well.

You might be able to look in to using the HTML5 [AppCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) or [File system API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Comment: I found a reference, but I could not be sure it is correct. I think file system api can help me

Comment: "Filesystem API spec should be considered dead"

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [HTML5 Offline Application Cache](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH7-SW1) in Safari / Webkit.

> Use the offline application cache to store HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and
>   media resources locally, to create web-based applications that work
>   even when a returning user is not connected to the Internet.

Comment: Doesn't work for audio. It will downnload, cache, but won't play back. Ios 5.2