# converting audio file to base64 using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, type-conversion, base64

I want to convert audio file into **base64** using **Javascript** only.

We can convert images into **base64** using canvas. But how can we convert audio files.

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Why do you want it in Base64 ? Is it for transmiting or to store locally ? Also, where do you get your file from, is it from an URL or from the client's computer ?

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878404/how-can-i-convert-mp3-file-to-base64-encoded-string

Comment: @RemyGrandin actually i have files in application's raw folder i want them to move to phone's local storage.

Comment: I'm doing it for tizen web app.In tizen i know how to convert base64 into audio file using file system  and to i can store locally.But i'm unable to convert audio file to base64.

Comment: why base64? is there some kind of restriction?

Comment: Not exactly.converting file to byte array also will work.But i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert mp3 file to base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878404/how-can-i-convert-mp3-file-to-base64-encoded-string)

Comment: It's not duplicate actually i was asking how to do programmatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can give the below code a try, it uses [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa)

```
function getData(audioFile, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var data = event.target.result.split(',')
         , decodedImageData = btoa(data[1]);                    // the actual conversion of data from binary to base64 format
        callback(decodedImageData);        
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(audioFile);
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue to covert audio data to base64 string.              @mido  btoa() is for string conversion to base64 not the audio data. If you may provide the audio encoding in base64 sting will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to convert an audio file to a base64 string with JavaScript:

```js
async function audioToBase64(audioFile) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.onload = (e) => resolve(e.target.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(audioFile);
  });
}
```

You can use it like this:

```html
<input oninput="audioToBase64(this.files[0]).then(result => console.log(result))" type="file">
```

This will `console.log` a string like `data:audio/mpeg;base64,//uYxAAAAA...` when a file is chosen in that filepicker.