# audio to base64 using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an audio Link:

```
var au='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-46a7f.appspot.com/o/Audio.mp3?alt=media&token=a4fa9b18-ab70-4bbc-8ae1-21639d411035';
```

I need to convert the audio to base64, because its play on mobile devices with a very big delay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting audio file to base64 using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161897/converting-audio-file-to-base64-using-javascript)

Comment: If you are thinking of doing this in a browser, the main issue I see is that the server wont let you access the raw audio

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.This audio file played on mobile very delayed.any other way to fix this pblm.

Answer (score 1):

Please see working plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/PFfebmnqH0eQR9I92v0G?p=preview, Its in Angular 2

Core Logic is JS method : 
HTML

```
<input type="file" id="filePicker" (change)="handleFileSelect($event)">
```

JavaScript:

```
handleFileSelect(evt){
      var files = evt.target.files;
      var file = files[0];

    if (files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload =this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  }



 _handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
     var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            this.base64textString= btoa(binaryString);
            console.log(btoa(binaryString));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.This audio file played on mobile very delayed.any other way to fix this pblm

Comment: @ANISUNDAR thats complete different question altogether, you will need to use something from  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API